# Polymer examples for transitioning paper-cards

Tags: polymer-1.0

We have a list of paper-cards in a dom-repeat, that ask survey questions.

We want to gray out/disable the other questions that are not in focus, and animate the transition from one question to the next, via a next button, etc. (And we will also add a progress bar at the bottom showing 1 of x questions have been answered).

I saw iron-swipeable, but it seems to want to just remove the card that I am currently on, but does not seem to load up the next card...

I also tried zero-list-hero, but not an example that does something similar, and cannot get the transition going.

What elements should I use? Any examples similar to what I am looking to do?